# Understanding a proof regarding direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

> $W_1,\dots,W_m$ are subspaces of the vector space $V$. Let $V=W_1 + \dots + W_m$. Proof that $V=W_1 \oplus \dots \oplus W_m \iff (W_1+\dots+W_i) \cap W_{i+1} = \{0\}$, for all $1\le i \le m-1$.

I'm having troubles understanding the proof given for the implication from right to left:

> Suppose that the sum is not direct, i.e. there exist an element $x=v_1+\dots+v_m=v_1'+\dots+v_m'$, with $v_j,v_j' \in W_j$ $(1\le i \le m)$, such that for at least one $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$: $v_i \ne v_i'$. Let's call $k \in \{1,\dots,m\}$ the index for which $v_k \ne v_k'$, while $v_l=v_l'$ for all $m \ge l > k$. Now we have: $x-x = \sum_{i=1}^m (v_i - v_i') = 0$. Following our choice for $k$ we get $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(v_i-v_i') = v_k' - v_k \ne 0$. **This implies that $(W_1+\dots+W_k)\cap W_{k+1}\ne \{0\}$**, a contradiction.

The very last sentence confuses me. How come $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(v_i-v_i') = v_k' - v_k \ne 0 \Rightarrow (W_1+\dots+W_k)\cap W_{k+1}\ne \{0\}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

It should actually read $(W_1+W_2+\cdots +W_{k-1})\cap W_k \neq \{0\}$. The left side the equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} (v_i-v_i' )=v_k'-v_k$ belongs to $W_1+W_2+\cdots +W_{k-1}$ and the right side to $W_k$ so the intersection of these two spaces is not $\{0\}$.